# Knockout observableArray not updating JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-accordion, knockout-3.0

I have updated my website to the latest JQuery, JQueryUI and KnockOutJS.

Since then my accordion refuses to update when I add items to my observerable array.  This works just fine when using KnocKOutJS version 2.0.0 with older versions for JQuery.

I have recreated the problem in JSFiddler and would appreciate any help.  The javascript is a heavily simplified version of my actual code.

http://jsfiddle.net/glenb/M9222/6/

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
My Model looks like this:

```
function ModelCollection() {
   var self = this;
   self.ModelItems = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.AddNewItem = function(){
      var newItem = new ModelItem();
      newItem.Name = "Added";
      modelCollectionApp.ModelItems.push(newItem);
  };
}

function ModelItem() {
   var self = this;
   self.Name = "";
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="knockOutBinding">
   <div data-bind="foreach: ModelItems, jqAccordion: {}">
      <h3>An Element Title</h3>
      <div>Some Content</div>
   </div>
   <button data-bind="click: AddNewItem">Add New Item</button>
</div>
```

Finally I initially populate it and bind it

```
var modelCollectionApp = new ModelCollection();

var modelItem = new ModelItem();
modelItem.Name = "test1";
modelCollectionApp.ModelItems.push(modelItem);

var modelItem = new ModelItem();
modelItem.Name = "test2";
modelCollectionApp.ModelItems.push(modelItem);

ko.applyBindings(modelCollectionApp, document.getElementById("knockOutBinding"));
```

Comment: Have you tried the knockout-jQuery fix? - http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but when I use that library I get: "Message: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." I dont think it plays well with ko foreach (<div data-bind="foreach: EventVenueDetailItemViewModels, accordion:{}">).

Comment: Sorry, havent tried it with accordion but I managed to get it working with tabs. I tried to make it work in your fiddle with no luck and decided to google it. Found someone with the same problem right here on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210897/multiple-nested-jquery-ui-accordion-generated-through-knockout-template-does-not

Comment: Thanks, I managed to eventually find some help from knockout themselves, posted below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that things have changed quiet drastically with regards to JQueryUI Widgets and Knockout in version 3.

Evan explains here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/knockoutjs/accordion/knockoutjs/OX6Lp_I_LoY/472sLkF5MTcJ

Bottom line is when binding the accordion in my code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ModelItems, jqAccordion: {collapsible: true}">
```

Before, you would pass in your config options like "{collapsible: true}".  This worked in older versions but now it has changed.  You should pass in the "ViewModel" instead.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ModelItems, jqAccordion: ModelItems">
```

The other thing that needed to change was in the update method you have to call ko.unwrap

```
var options = valueAccessor();
ko.unwrap(options)  // <-- this is important!
```

If you want to customize the accordion, you have to do it in the init section of the binding like this:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
   var options = {
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      animate: "easeOutQuint",
      heightStyle: "content"
   };

   $(element).accordion(options);
   $(element).bind("valueChanged", function () {
      ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor);
   });
}
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/glenb/M9222/7/

I hope this helps someone out there, upvote if it helped you!